# Box hidden when created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website I have a button which will create a box when clicked. If that box is visible and the user clicks outside of it, it should be hidden. The problem I have is that the box is hidden right after it is created.

This is the piece of code I use to remove the box if the user clicks outside of it. I struggle understanding why it is triggered when I create the box, because it is not really visible yet.

```js
function createBox(){

    var output = "";
    
    output += '<div class="single-box">';
    output += '</div>';
    
    $("#list-box").html(output);
    
    document.getElementById('list-box').style.display = 'block';
}


$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.single-box').length) {
        if($('.single-box').is(":visible")) {

            var output = "";

            $("#list-box").html(output);
         
        document.getElementById('list-box').style.display = 'none';
          
        }
    }        
});
```

```css
#list-box{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 z-index: 500;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
}

.single-box{
 z-index: 1000;
 top: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: white;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 right: calc(50% - 250px);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
 text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p onclick="createBox();">
Create box
</p>
<div id="list-box"></div>
```

Comment: Well because the click event that happens on the paragraph element bubbles up to document, and to that you've attached a handler that hides the element if a certain condition is not met. That condition is whether the originally clicked element is itself a/the `.single-box` element or a descendant of it ... which it obviously isn't. If you want an easy way around this, then stop messing with onclick attributes in the HTML, but attach the handler for the paragraph the proper jQuery way as well - and then cancel the bubbling up for that event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#somebutton").click(function () {
  $("#container").append('<div class="box">Your hidden box is now visible</div>');

});

var mouse_is_inside = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_is_inside) $('.box').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="somebutton">
Your button
</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: you should try the code snippet before to save your answer. I think you forget to choose jQuery library, you've got an `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`error.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

```js
let mouse_inside = false ;

$("#somebutton").click(function () {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'box';
  $("#container").append(div);

  $('.box').hover(function(){ 
      mouse_inside=true; 
  }, function(){ 
      mouse_inside=false; 
  });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
      mouse_inside || $('.box').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}

#container .box { background-color: blue; width:40px; height:40px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="somebutton">
ADD A BOX BELOW
</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: you missed that he wand to close the box when clicked out of it not the parent box , you should close the blue box when clicked on the red : ), et merci

Comment: Fixed, @M0ns1f (just a typo) ;).

Comment: soyer le bienvenue : )

Comment: Then De rien ! ^^'

Answer (score -1):

here you go try using this steps , first check the `element` clicked `id`

if the element is the button you want it to creat that box trigger your `creatBox()` else if element clicked is the box do nothing else empty `#list-box`and hide it :

```js
function createBox(){

    var output = "";
    
    output += '<div class="single-box">';
    output += '</div>';
    
    $("#list-box").html(output);
    
    $('#list-box').show();
}


$(document).click(function(e) {

    var target = $(e.target);
    var id = target.attr('id');
    var eclass = target.attr('class');
    if(id == "creatbox"){
      createBox();
      target.prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else if(eclass == "single-box")
    {
     return;
    }
    else {
    $("#list-box").html('');
    $('#list-box').hide();
    $('#creatbox').prop("disabled",false);
    }
    
});
```

```css
#list-box{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 z-index: 500;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
}

.single-box{
 z-index: 1000;
 top: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: white;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 right: calc(50% - 250px);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
 text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="creatbox">
Create box
</button>
<div id="list-box"></div>
```